# how recognise clusterhead in ns2.35

Tags: ns2

I want to identify the ClusterHead in the CBRP protocol in code c++. How can I do this? Can I recognize the from Trace file? 
Os ubuntu 16.04 & ns2.35

I need your help very much

Comment: I think the only "ns2 application" that can do **advertiseClusterHead** is LEACH. See how in the configuration file `mit/uAMPS/ns-leach.tcl`. Example output, the year 2012 sample leach.out : `ns-2.34/mit/leach_sims/test_simulations/leach/leach.out` → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUkFKQ1FTTDk1Y1E/view?usp=sharing ... **Code** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUDB4VmI4ZVdZTjg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

C++ code can be found in `Mannasim` :

```
$ grep -Rin advertiseClusterHead *
leach/app/leachApp.cc:187:      new LeachEvent(&LeachApp::advertiseClusterHead),
leach/app/leachApp.cc:236: void LeachApp::advertiseClusterHead()
leach/app/leachApp.h:162:       virtual void advertiseClusterHead();
```

Mannasim code https://github.com/paultsr/ns-allinone-2.35

```
$ git clone https://github.com/paultsr/ns-allinone-2.35.git
```

Note : There is no similar C++ code in the "MIT uAMPS LEACH". It's all otcl (tcl) code for the cluster head "print-out".

Comment: @ Knud Larsen    //How can I do this if I want to print the node of the cluster head in the Trace file??

Comment: »» print the node of the cluster head in the Trace file «« : Probably like the code mentioned in my answers : Otcl or C++.

Comment: @ Knud Larsen    >>How to do this, I create a file to print nodes. The file will remain empty

Comment: @ Knud Larsen >> 
If I define a Boolean variable in class NeighborTableCformationHandler that specifies a cluster, how can I use this variable in OTcl?